# C++ Difference between 'int' and 'INT'

Tags: c++, int

I was looking at some code on msdn and they used `INT` instead of `int`.

I googled and checked other questions here, all of them were titled int between int, and or in C#.

I am wondering if it would be fine to update all my code with `INT`

Is there any difference?

Comment: INT is just a typedef/#define, follow it in the Windows headers to see what it actually is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INT` is a typedef of `int` provided in some headers provided by Microsoft for Windows programming. Whenever you are calling a Windows function that has a parameter of type `INT`, feel free to use this type in your code.

You should not use `INT` in place of `int` in general code, especially if you want it to be portable. There is no guarantee that `INT` will be defined as anything in a C++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use `INT` as you would `int`. Since I don't have the code, I can't tell you why they used it, but my guess would be that in some include, they had the line `#define INT int`.